# Modifying Spring beans programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm currently developing a web application. I know some basics of Spring, however I haven't been working with it that much, hence I've decided to improve my Spring-skills and I've faced a problem that I can't really find a good solution for.

I'd like to implement in my app a feature that will allow the user to configure everything without touching any config file (e.g. spring beans), basically the person that wants to deploy, launch and use the app should only copy the .WAR file into for example tomcat and all the configuration should be done within the app (like in OpenFire for example).

So I imagine that the user deploys the app goes to certain URL and everything is done through UI, he is being asked about some parameters (e.g. DB connection details) once all details are given everything is stored in cfg file, app restarted and the configuration process is over.

I wanted to have all the configuration details in spring beans, but I've discovered that I can't really change them programmatically (one solution would be to modify the file 'out of spring' and reload the app context after wards - is that good approach?).
Another one would be to store xml file in WEB-INF for example and save the data there once it's gathered from the user, but then how to load the data from non-bean file into application context?

Any advices appriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep such values in properties file. You can use property file values in [spring bean](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring/).
Also you can update values in properties file with user input accepted through UI.

Comment: That looks promising, I'll give it a shot and report right back, thanks Ajinkya!

Comment: Yeah, it works great! I can link the property file with the bean and modify the property file, awsome. Now i only need to check how to reload the context but that should be straight forward (hopefuly :)). Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can access ever bean through the `ApplicationContext` class and it subclasses. From here, you could call the getters and setters for proeprties on all of your beans; however it's of note that the application context will already have been created, as will the `BeanFactory`, so there will be some lifecycle steps you have missed.

Setting properties that are not related to lifecycle on your own beans would certainly be feasible, but I wouldn't recommend trying to change properties of 'infrastructure' beans (e.g. transaction management, package-scanning) after the context has been set up and started.

If your target user is a naive user, perhaps you could offer the functionality to amend a properties file, and then programmatically reload the web application, and have your Spring context load its properties using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` or `PropertyOverrideConfigurer`.

If your target user is an 'internal' IT-savvy user, then you could also make use of JMX, which would allow you to change the properties of every bean in the context using `jconsole` or similar.